# how I can convert a text file to json with the given keys?

Tags: python, json, file, txt

I have a text file like this:

```
[{"Keywords":"softeware developer","Results":[{"categoryId":"1234","categoryName":"lead developer","score":"0.7412536859512329"},{"categoryId":"1657","categoryName":"developer consultant","score":"0.6560295867919922"},{"categoryId":"2324","categoryName":"etl developer","score":"0.6531170797348023"},{"categoryId":"2632","categoryName":"oracle developer","score":"0.6264872598648071"},{"categoryId":"1232","categoryName":"sharepoint developer","score":"0.6262540578842163"}]}]
```

I am wondering can I convert it to a Jason file with the following keys?
`Keywords` , `Results`

If I can make results separate would be perfect. if not it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import json
with open("file.txt", "rb") as f:
    content = json.load(f)
with open("fileJson.txt", "wb") as fout:
    json.dump(content, fout, indent=1)
```

or visit [Text to Json](https://cppsecrets.com/users/78156511411711010910311111910097575764103109971051084699111109/Python-JSON-Convert-Text-file-to-JSON-in-Python.php) for answers

Answer (score 0):

Not a python method but you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) on your terminal

```sh
cat file.txt | jq "." > file.json
```

To separate them

```sh
cat file.txt | jq ".[].Keywords" > keywords.json
cat file.txt | jq ".[].Results" > results.json
```

(this will apply to every entry in the array, if you want just one add the index e.g. `jq ".[0].Keywords`)

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import json
>>> with open('$path_to_file') as f: j = json.load(f)
>>> jk = j[0]['Keywords']
>>> jr = j[0]['Results']
>>> with open('k.txt', 'w') as f: json.dump({'Keywords':jk},f)
>>> with open('r.txt', 'w') as f: json.dump({'Results':jr},f)
```